# How to add multiple bars/lines in one single bar chart?

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, bar-chart, data-science, data-analysis

I've calculated the average reading, writing and math scores based on gender . Now, I want to display it using bar chart.

> df

```
        math score  reading score   writing score
gender          
female  63.633205   72.608108   72.467181
male    68.728216   65.473029   63.311203
```

Above is the output of my calculation on "Students" Data-Set and I've assigned the output to another Data-frame "df" as shown above . I've tried to create a bar plot to understand all the average scores bases on gender . But the bars are overlapping , how can I understand each factor separately based on "gender" division . I want three bars for each gender division.

```
  ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
  w = 0.4
  ax.bar(df.index,df['math score'], width = w, color = 'g')
  ax.bar(df.index, df['reading score'], width = w , color = 'b')
```

[This is what I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CEAk.png)

Comment: Did you try pandas plot, e.g. `df.plot.bar()`?  See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html

Comment: No , I did'nt use it . Infact I don't know pandas plot().

Comment: Yes pandas plot function works. Thanks JohanC